# How do I calculate the variance of a mean difference effect size that has been converted to Fisher's z for meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

To be able to compare different types of effect sizes, I am converting my effect sizes that are originally mean differences into correlation coefficients. I am using the following formula:

d <- (t * (n.1 + n.2))/(sqrt(n.1 * n.2) * sqrt(df))

where t is the t-statistic and n1 and n2 the number in each group being compared (I am following formula from Nakagawa and Cuthill 2007 Biological Reviews). I am then converting my d into r, and then using the z-transformation of it for further analysis as follows:

r <- d/sqrt((d^2) + a)

where a <- ((n.1 + n.2)^2)/(n.1 * n.2)

z <- 0.5 * log((1 + r)/(1 - r))

What I am not sure about is how I calculate the variance of my new z.

If my original effect size was the correlation coefficient, I would simply use:
var.z <- (1/sqrt(n - 3))^2

but given my original effect size was a mean difference, I feel I should be accounting for the unbalanced numbers in each original group being compared.

Any help appreciated.